# Add field to all custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I know how to add fields to custom post types one at a time.

I was wondering if there is a way to add a field to the default post type as well as all the custom post types at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `add_meta_box()` function with an array of post types unfortunately although it would be a good core contribution.

The way to do this at the moment is to get an array of your post types and loop over them calling your `add_meta_box()` line for each one eg:

```
foreach( get_post_types() as $type ) {
    add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
}
```

You can filter the specific post types you get back if you need more control by passing an array into `get_post_types()` with the post type criteria you want to match eg. `'public' => true`.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. It would be useful to be use a hook to inject meta boxes when you create a custom post type.